# How to use conditional statements with non boolean types when generating code templates in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, templates

If `MyParameter` is supplied, I want this code block generated. The problem is it never generates whether `MyParameter` is supplied or not. It seems that conditional statements only work for `boolean` parameters. In my case `MyParameter` is of type `string`.

```
public class MyClass
{
    #if (MyParameter)
    public string MyParameter { get; set; }
    ---#endif
}
```

I tried to do this

```
public class MyClass
{
     #if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyParameter))
     public string MyParameter { get; set; }
     ---#endif
}
```

But unlike the first, this always generates even when `MyParameter` is null or empty. I have set the `defaultValue` for my parameter to `""` in `template.json` but the condition still always evaluate as `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a computed setting to your `template.json` file and use that in your source. For example:

```
"MyParameter": {
    "type": "parameter",
    "datatype": "text",
    "defaultValue": ""
    ...
},
"IsMyParameterEmpty": {
    "type": "computed",
    "value": "MyParameter == \"\""
}
```

Then in your C# source:

```
public class MyClass
{
    #if (!IsMyParameterEmpty)
    public string MyParameter { get; set; }
    ---#endif
}
```

Comment: i tried this but the conditon is always evaluated as true even when MyParamter is supplied or not supplied. When MyParameter is not supplied, it generates the whole line with the MyParameter key exactly like this `public string MyParameter {get; set;}` Whereas, I just want it gone if MyParameter is not supplied

Comment: I would need to see your code to give any further advice. I have tested the above and it works.

Comment: I missed setting the defaultValue of MyParameter to empty string. That was the issue.